# How do I force the SIP keyboard on Windows Mobile to read new settings from the registry?

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm disabling auto-complete and auto-suggestion on Windows Mobile 6.1 by setting the following registry keys:

```
HKCU\ControlPanel\Sip\SuggWords => 0
HKCU\ControlPanel\Sip\SuggAutoCorr => 0
```

However it doesn't seem to change anything until I restart the device. The control panel applet that exposes these settings somehow tells the SIP keyboard to reload, but how?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common mechanisms the OS uses for these types of things is broadcasting a [WM_SETTINGSCHANGE message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497(VS.85).aspx).  I don't know that this is what the CPL does in this instance, but it's certainly worth a try.

Comment: I'll give this a try in the next sprint that touches that code, thanks Chris!